# How do I match multiple columns in two separate files and only output the rows where all three column values match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, awk

I have two large files.  The first looks like this:

```
PLATEID MJD FIBERID LGM_TOT_P50 OH_P50  SFR_TOT_P50 SPECSFR_TOT_P50 Index
------- --- ------- ----------- ------  ----------- --------------- -----
266 51602   1   10.294701   -9999.0 -0.5206503  -10.87437   1
266 51602   2   11.162018   -9999.0 -0.34972167 -11.567741  2
266 51602   3   -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 3
```

The second looks like this:

```
col1    col2_1  col7_1  col3_2  col4_1  col5_2  col7_2  col4_2  col3    col4    col5    Index
----    ------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ----    ----    ----    -----
114 2244    14.2824 42.796721558    0.941932669 0.1921383   -11.9826088 -0.233108   51871   409 601 1
325 3669    14.0476 56.956485129    1.027377082 0.1799167   -10.5876274 0.6275974   52901   1242    375 2
351 3806    14.3661 58.387142242    1.042578256 0.0762465   -11.5828028 -0.6205882  52901   1242    610 3
```

I know these are very messy, but essentially I want to combine these two make one file.  I want to match the following columns:

MJD (file 1) with col3 (file 2) 
PLATEID (file 1) with col4 (file 2) 
FIBERID (file 1) with col 5 (file 2)

The new file should **only** contain the rows where all three of the above conditions are met:

```
col1    col2_1  col7_1  col3_2  col4_1  col5_2  col7_2  col4_2  col3    col4    col5    Index PLATEID MJD FIBERID LGM_TOT_P50 OH_P50  SFR_TOT_P50 SPECSFR_TOT_P50 Index
721 37102   14.1816 167.791828441   0.625389832 0.0250531   -10.6558456 -0.4704049  -1  -1  -1  7 -1    -1  -1  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 7
```

So far, I've tried this awk command:

```
awk -F'|' '
FNR==NR{
    a[$9,$10,$11]=(a[$9,$10,$11]?a[$9,$10,$11] ORS:"")$0
    next
}
(($2,$1,$3) in a){
    print a[$2,$1,$3]
}' file2 file1 > catalog.txt
```

But this output file ends up being completely blank.  I also tried a Pandas DataFrame, but I got a TypeError.  My code was

```
f = pd.DataFrame(data=file2[1:,1:],
                index=file2[1:,0:],
                columns=file2[0:,1:])
```

(I did the same for file 1).  The error was:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-f7663abb5cdb> in <module>
      5 sdss = pd.read_csv("/Users/emmalovett/research/galSpecExtra-dr8", header = 2)
      6 
----> 7 f = pd.DataFrame(data=IDcat[1:,1:],
      8                 index=IDcat[1:,0:],
      9                 columns=IDcat[0:,1:])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2644                 )
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
   2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '(slice(1, None, None), slice(1, None, None))' is an invalid key
```

Any help is appreciated-- I'm not experienced in awk or Pandas.  TIA!!

Comment: Your awk script starts with `awk -F'|'` which means it expects `|`-separated data but there are no `|`s in your posted sample input. If your real data is `|`-separated then post `|`-separated sample data so you don't end up with a solution to a problem you don't have. Also add the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: @EdMorton ah, okay, I took out the -F ' | ' and that seemed to work.  I added the expected output to my question, but I'm afraid it doesn't make much sense how it looks.  I want the output to have **all** the columns of **both** files; right now, the awk command is only giving me the rows of file 2 where the columns between the two files match.  Is there a way for me to include the columns from file 1 to the output?  I also noticed that the output is MUCH larger than file 1 or 2, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The expected output you post has to be the output you expect from the input you post, not just some random line of text that might be output from some different input. We need something we can test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    a[$9 FS $10 FS $11] = $0
    next
}
{ key = $2 FS $1 FS $3 }
key in a {
    print a[key], $0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
```

It doesn't produce any output given the input you posted so idk if that's really what you expected or not.